# MySQL stored procedure with dynamic query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am aware that MySQL triggers don't support dynamic queries. I tried creating a stored procedure with some dynamic queries (with PREPARE and EXECUTE) and then calling it from a trigger but it did not work. It is throwing the same error, that is "Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger" even though I have my dynamic queries in the procedure, not in the trigger.

This might be a behavior of MySQL(v5.7), but I could not find anything on the documentation regarding this limitation, it mentions only about trigger and functions.

If this is indeed an intentional behavior of MySQL then, is there any way to workaround it?

My requirement is, I want to copy some rows from a table after insert, to some other table depending on some criteria. This other table name will be dynamic.

I searched but could not find anything that solves my problem.

Comment: “I tried creating a stored procedure with some dynamic queries (with PREPARE and EXECUTE) and then calling it from a trigger but it did not work.” Tricking MySQL wont work MySQL is smart and defects this there are no workarounds

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was not trying to trick MySQL, since the dynamic query is allowed in procedures and procedures can be called from anywhere, including the trigger, I thought this will work.

Comment: No wont work “The trigger cannot use the CALL statement to invoke stored procedures that return data to the client or that use dynamic SQL. (Stored procedures are permitted to return data to the trigger through OUT or INOUT parameters.)” its in the manual

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ok, thanks for clarifying that it is not possible and no workaround. I Guess, I have to do it in some other way.

Comment: “My requirement is, I want to copy some rows from a table after insert, to some other table depending on some criteria. This other table name will be dynamic.” Well INSERT INTO ... SELECT can copy between tables with a WHERE filter